# Передача значения переменной из функции, вызываемой по keydown Javascript

Tags: javascript, keydown

Есть код

```
      var isKeyPressed=0; 
  document.onkeydown = function (){
    isKeyPressed=1;
  };
  if (isKeyPressed) 
     alert("Привет!");
```

Почему при нажатии кнопки не выводит alert? Т.е. почему значение переменной isKeyPressed не меняется, не передаётся из функции? (То, что alert можно вывести, вставив его внутрь функции, я понимаю. Вопрос именно про переменную)

Answer (score 2):

На момент выполнения alert'a, судя по данному коду, переменная =0. Читайте комментарии к коду ниже "с точки зрения браузера (того, кто выполняет код)":

```
//первый шаг: установили переменную в значение "0", все ясно.
var isKeyPressed=0; 
//второй шаг: так, когда нажмут клавишу выполню эту функцию. Ок. А пока даже заглядывать туда не буду.  
document.onkeydown = function (){
    //четвертый шаг (в неизвестный момент времени после остальных): ага, клавишу нажали, присваиваем переменной значение "1".
    isKeyPressed=1;
};
//третий шаг: так, чему там равна переменная? ага, "0". Значит не заходим сюда. 
if (isKeyPressed) 
    alert("Привет!");
```

У вас же алерт вываливается не когда вы на клавишу нажимаете, а сразу при загрузке страницы. А переменная в 1 выставляется только после нажатия.